# can i backup domain from one glassfish installation to another?

Tags: glassfish

i have 2 machines on which same version of glassfish is installed say A and B. they are nix based. on both the machines glassfish is hosting same applications. glasfish B is facing some issue which we are not able to sort. glassfish A and applications on it are working perfectly. can i take a backup-domain on glassfish A and restore it on glassfish B. ? in other words do domain configuration contains machine specific information or anything that might make this thing not possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You should be able to do that.  We went to lengths to make the configuration not machine-specific.

I recommend that you first backup GF "B" just to be safe.

If you have GF server instances (not domain) running on another machine, they have a config file that points back to the domain's host.  You would need to edit that file if the domain host changed.